# makefile for C on UNIX

Tags: c, unix, makefile

Hello I'm starting to learn C and Unix programming. However I am really confused on makefiles. I created a simple c program that displays lines of text with printf (aloha.c). How should I go about creating a makefile? Will it be a separate .c file in the same directory or text file?

```
/*Will output aloha!*/
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   printf("Aloha!\n");
   printf("Hello World!\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: please edit your question to include your code. :)

Comment: Added code to my post :o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest makefile would be something like:

```
aloha: aloha.c Makefile
    gcc -o aloha aloha.c
```

(remembering that's a tab character at the start if the second line). It's usually named `Makefile` in the same directory as the source, so that you just need to enter `make` on the command line.

From there, it can get incredibly complex, depending on how you need to tie different objects together.

You'll notice I've included `Makefile` itself in the list of dependencies - that's so any change to the makefile redoes *everything* since all bets are off as to what has to be recompiled, relinked and so on.

Answer (score 1):

As paxdiablo answered previously, that's the simpliest Makefile you can write for your C file. However, Makefiles have much wider use. They enable you to manage and build your project automatically and in a very organized way. A Makefile consists of one or more rules looking like this:

```
target: dependencies
[tab] system command
```

However, you can also add some variables to simplfy your makefile. There are two types of variables: recursively expanded and simply expanded variables. Actually, variables can represent directories, lists of file names, options to pass to compilers, programs to run...

*N.B: Variables in the makefile are case sensitive, meaning that CC and cc (for example)are considered different!*

In the other hand, in order to create a makefile, create a text file, write your content and change the name of the file to Makefile.

*N.B: When using "make", it executes directly the file titled "Makefile", If you have another Makefile in the directory that you want to execute, you should add the name of the file to execute in front of the make command.*